# Glimpse does not show the update sql statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, glimpse

For debugging my MVC application, I installed Glimpse (Glimpse.Ado, Glimpse.AspNet, Glimpse.Core, Glimpse.EF6, Glimpse.Mvc5). The SQL tab conveniently displays select statements, but not updates. What am I doing wrong?

I am trying to look at what Entity Framework does on the following code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    //public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,FirstName,LastName,Gender,Salary,DepartmentId")] Employee employee)
    public ActionResult Edit(EmployeeViewModel employeeViewModel)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //db.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;
                var employee = db.Employees.Find(employeeViewModel.Id);
                employee.FirstName = employeeViewModel.FirstName;
                employee.LastName = employeeViewModel.LastName;
                employee.Gender = employeeViewModel.Gender;
                employee.Salary = Convert.ToInt32(employeeViewModel.Salary);
                employee.DepartmentId = employeeViewModel.DepartmentId;

                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Salary", "Failed to save employee data: " + ex.Message);
        }
        ViewBag.DepartmentId = new SelectList(db.Departments, "Id", "Name", employeeViewModel.DepartmentId);
        return View(employeeViewModel);
    }
```

But of course my question is not about this code, but about Glimpse.
Thanks.